# Find the interval of convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

[image]

Assuming that $x$ is fixed, I wrote:

[image]

And then I used the Ratio test:

[image]

So I get the interval of $1$ $<$ $x$ $<$ $3$. However, my question is: how can $sin$ be convergent at all? I mean, its' values just randomly jump inside interval of $[$ $-1$$;$$1$$]$, how can it get some exact value?

Answer (score 0):

The way these tests are written, it's probably

$  \sum \left( \sin\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2 + 1} \right) (x-2)^n$
which is much easier.

If it is, indeed,

$  \sum  \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2 + 1}  (x-2)^n \right)$
then it's a sine of a positive argument when $x > 2$ (and therefore, basically, your calculation works) and alternating series when $x < 2$. Thus, for $x < 2$, you can use alternating series test.

Also, keep in mind the inequality $\sin |x| < |x|$.

How can $sin$ converge at all? If it's a sine of something small, then it does not randomly jump all over $[-1,1]$, but is also small.